# jQuery Reset checked radio options on hitting back button

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button, back-button, checked

I have a form where the radio button options get saved upon hitting the submit button. But when I hit the back button, the radio inputs should reset and check to the default option. However, even though I have the first input radio options with the "checked" attribute, they still are not checked after hitting the back button.
Here is my sample code:

```
<label id="label_new_home"><input class="radio_shuttle_pickup" type="radio" name="data[shuttle_pickup][cat]" checked value="airport"><span>Airport</span></label>
<label id="label_new_home"><input class="radio_shuttle_pickup" type="radio" name="data[shuttle_pickup][cat]" value="hotel"><span>Hotel</span></label>
<label id="label_new_home"><input class="radio_shuttle_pickup" type="radio" name="data[shuttle_pickup][cat]" value="other"><span>Other</span></label>
```

I've tried the following methods with no luck:

```
$("#form3 input[type=radio]").button("refresh"); 

$("#form3 input[type=radio]").prop("checked", false);

$('#form3').get(0).reset();

$(':input', '#form3')
.not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
.val('')
.prop('checked', false)
.prop('selected', false)

$("input.radio_shuttle_pickup[value=airport]").prop("checked", true);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have all this inside doc ready block?

Comment: Yes, I've tried putting it in the `$(document).ready` function. Still doesn't work.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using ? For jQuery <1.6, you have to use `.attr('checked', 'checked');`

Comment: Are you referring to the browsers back button?

Comment: In your code how are you listening to the window's `unload` event so you know when to reset the checkboxes? ... **Also IDs are meant to be unique.**

Comment: @PeterKA The functions are running on page load. I know ID's are meant to be unique. Someone else built that portion of the code.

Comment: Are you using jQuery-UI ? `.button()` is jQuery-ui's property

Comment: @EdenSource Yes version 1.11.4.

Comment: Please create a demo, preferably a snippet here.

Comment: `reset()` isn't working in jQuery/jQuery-UI, seems to work after commenting `$('#form3').get(0).reset();`

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed the problem. The PHP code didn't pick up the last page variable which didn't trigger the javascript code that checked the radio buttons.